# Is there a problem of plane geometry whose analytic reformulation gives a polynomial non-solvable by radicals?

Tags: polynomials, euclidean-geometry, plane-geometry

[This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/31368/84284) explains that any elementary plane geometry problem can be reduced to the existence of a solution of a polynomial system (called the analytic reformulation).

*Question*: Is there a problem of elementary plane geometry whose analytic reformulation gives a polynomial non-solvable by radicals?

Comment: You can translate the search for the root of a polynomial into a geometric problem.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen: Nice! What would be the problem of *elementary* plane geometry translating the search of the root of $P(x) = x^5-x+1$ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I take for granted that  $x^5-x+1=0$ has Galois group $S_5$ and hence is not solvable by radicals. It can be translated into a geometric problem:

Given $A,B$, find all remaining point so that you obtain a figure where

- triangles $ABC$, $ACD$, $ADE$, $AEF$, $AFG$ are similar
- $ABCG$ is a parallelogram

Note that identifying $\vec{AB}$ with $1\in\Bbb C$ and $\vec{AC}$ with $x\in\Bbb C$, the first bullit point ensures that $\vec{AG}=x^5$ and the second ensures that $x^5+1=x$.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for adding the graphics!